# Is every pointwise-weakly continuous one-parameter group of automorphisms of B(H) given by a Hamiltonian?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, von-neumann-algebras, quantum-mechanics, automorphism-groups

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space, $\mathscr B(\mathcal H)$ be the von Neumann algebra of all bounded operators on $\mathcal H$, and let $\sigma $ be a one-parameter group
of automorphisms of  $\mathscr B(\mathcal H)$, meaning simply that $\sigma $ is a group homomorphism
$$
  \sigma :{\mathbb R}\to \text{Aut}\big (\mathscr B(\mathcal H)\big ),
  $$
where $
\text{Aut}(
\mathscr B(\mathcal H)
)
$ is the group formed by all *-automorphisms of $\mathscr B(\mathcal H)$.

In quantum mechanics such one-parameter groups are crucial ingredients since they are seen as the time evolution of observables and they almost always have the
form
$$
  \sigma _t(A) = e^{itH}Ae^{-itH},\quad (t\in {\mathbb R}),\quad (A\in \mathscr B(\mathcal H)),
  $$
where $H$  is a (possibly unbounded,  densely defined) self-adjoint operator on $\mathcal H$, sometimed called
the Hamiltonian of the system.

It is almost foklore that all "nice" one-parameter groups are of the above form, and in fact Blackadar states precisely this
in Theorem (I.7.4.10)
[B. Blackadar, Operator Algebras Theory of C*-Algebras and von Neumann Algebras, Operator Algebras and Non-Commutative
Geometry III,  Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences
Volume 122, 2006], where "nice" is taken to be "strongly continuous".  However the meaning of "strongly continuous" here
is a bit unclear since it could
either be
taken to be:

(1) for every $A\in \mathscr B(\mathcal H)$, the map
$$
  t\in {\mathbb R} \mapsto   \sigma _t(A)\in \mathscr B(\mathcal H)
  $$
is continuous in the *norm* topology of $\mathscr B(\mathcal H)$, or

(2) for every $A\in \mathscr B(\mathcal H)$, and every
$\xi \in \mathcal H$, the map
$$
  t\in {\mathbb R} \mapsto   \sigma _t(A)\xi \in \mathcal H
  $$
is continuous in the *norm* topology of $\mathcal H$ (this should be called pointwise-strongly continuous).

Unfortunately Blackadar makes no further comments on the meaning of "strongly continuous" and neither does he give a
reference  for this fact.

Even though (1) seems to be the natural interpretation of "strongly continuous" in Theorem (I.7.4.10), given the context
and the results discussed right before this result,
it should be said that this  is not a very interesting condition since it fails for the one-parameter groups defined in terms
of an unbounded Hamiltonian, as above.

As this is something I need for a project I'm involved in, I spent some time searching for a reference, but I could not
find it!  This was indeed was a big surprise, given the fundamental importance of this result not only in quantum
mechanics, but also in
many other applications.

Frustrated with my bad luck I ended up proving this result by myself,  using an even weaker condition, namely

(3) for every $A\in \mathscr B(\mathcal H)$, and every
$\xi , \eta \in \mathcal H$, the map
$$
  t\in {\mathbb R} \mapsto   \langle \sigma _t(A)\xi , \eta \rangle \in {\mathbb R}
  $$
is continuous (this should be called pointwise-weakly continuous).

My proof turned out to be rather convoluted, and in it I used Theorem 4.13 of  [R. Kadison, Transformations
of states in operator theory and dynamics, Topology Vol. 3, Suppl. 2, pp. 177-198], which requires a different
continuity condition,  namely that $\sigma $ be continuous in the *bounded-weak* topology of $\text{Aut}(\mathscr
B(\mathcal H))$, meaning that
$$
  \lim_{t\to t_0}\ \sup_{\buildrel{\scriptstyle A\in \mathscr B(\mathcal H)}\over{\Vert A\Vert \leq 1}}
  \Big |\big \langle \big (\rho _t(A)-\rho _{t_0}(A)\big )\xi ,\xi \big \rangle \Big | = 0,
  $$
for every $t_0$ in ${\mathbb R}$, and every $\xi $ in $\mathcal H$.

Despite my long years pretending to be a mathematician, I am
embarrassed to admit that I have never heard of this topolopgy before!

In a nutshel, I think I proved that
pointwise-weakly continuous one-parameter groups are automatically bounded-weakly continuous.   My questions
therefore are:

**Question 1**.  Is there a reference for the fact that every pointwise-weakly continuous one-parameter group of
automorphisms is given by a Hamiltonian, as above?

**Question 2**.  Where else is the bounded-weak topolopgy on $\text{Aut}(\mathscr B(\mathcal H))$ used nowadays?

---

EDIT 1.  Based on some comments below,  it is perhaps worth mentioning that the main topologies mentioned above,  namely the
pointwise-strong,  pointwise-weak,   and bounded-weak topologies,  are all topologies on the set of bounded linear maps
from $\mathscr B(\mathcal H)$ to $\mathscr B(\mathcal H)$, rather than from  $\mathcal H$ to  $\mathcal H$.

EDIT 2.  I should have said that (2) and (3) are in fact equivalent, the reason being that the weak-operator topology is
well known to coincide with the strong-operator topology on unitary operators, and also that it is enough to test these
conditions when $A$ is a unitary operator (as these linearly span $\mathscr B(\mathcal H)$).

Comment: Of course you are correct, but unfortunately Blackadar gives no indication that this is the case.

Comment: I think this is the same as asking about unitary groups $U(t)$ (that is, $U(t)$ is a unitary operator on a Hilbert space for each fixed $t$ and $U(s+t)=U(s)U(t)$). One direction is certainly obvious. Assuming this, Stone's theorem (that is, the statement that $U(t)=e^{itH}$ for a self-adjoint $H$) works if we only assume $U$ to be weakly measurable, which is considerably weaker than your condition (3).

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups) on Stone's theorem explains the standard meaning of "strongly continuous" in this context.

Comment: There is a result showing the implication "weakly continuous implies strongly continuous", which is quite involved, in the book by Engel and Nagel (One-Parameter Semigroups of Operators). You find it there as Theorem I.5.8 on page 40.

It is likely that you can rephrase the Port-Hamiltonian form in a way such that the result can be applied.

Comment: @NikWeaver, I think the wikipedia page you mention only deals with one-parameter groups of **unitary** operators on a Hilbert space, rather than one-parameter groups of **automorphisms** of $B(H)$, which is the case in point here.

Comment: @ChristianRemling, please note that there is a difference between **unitary operators** on Hilbert's space on the one hand, and **automorphisms** of $B(H)$, on the other.  I think you are referring to operator valued maps, while I am dealing with maps taking values in the set of operators from $B(H)$ to $B(H)$.

Comment: @JulianHölz, I guess this result is not very difficult to prove since the weak-operator topology is well known to coincide with the strong-operator topology on unitary operators on Hilbert's space.  But, as in my comments above, I am dealing with topologies on the set of linear operators from $B(H)$ to $B(H)$, rather than from $H$ to $H$.  It is true that this result applies in this more general case but, in the absence of a good description for the Banach space dual of $B(H)$, it is not really useful.

Comment: @Ruy Every automorphism of $B(H)$ is implemented by a unitary. But I’m not sure how to lift a group homomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to Aut(B(H))$ to a group homomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to U(H)$, especially with a need to ensure some continuity property.

Comment: @DavidGao,  YES, this is the key question: whether a certain 2-cocycle is a coboundary with the appropriate continuity conditions.

Comment: @ChristianRemling.  Quoting your comment with a few remarks: *"Then $σ_t(P)$ is the projection onto $\text{span}(Ue)$, so we recover the image* $Ue$,  **up to a scalar multiple**, *for any
$e$  and thus reconstruct $U$ itself,*  **up to a scalar**."  The devil is that scalar!  It leads to a 2-cocycle and, once you
get it to be regular enough, the fact that the cohomology of $ℝ$ is trivial should do  the trick.

Comment: I see. Even assuming my apparently incorrect assumption about the possibility of recovering $U(t)$ from $\sigma_t$, I was having trouble deducing the (weak) measurability of $U(t)$ from that of $\sigma_t$, though I perhaps didn't try hard enough. (Measurability of $|\langle x, U(t)y\rangle |$ is easy, but I couldn't get information on the phase.)

Comment: This might be wrong, but in finite dimensions, can you combine the fact that $SU(n)$ is the universal covering of $PU(n)$ (so that there is a continuous lift $\mathbb{R} \to SU(n)$, though no longer necessarily a group homomorphism) with a cohomology argument to prove the result? I’m not sure if there’s any analogy of this in infinite dimensions, but perhaps the fact that $U(n)$ is weakly contractible (under either norm or strong operator topology) is useful?

Comment: @DavidGao, the hard cohomological work has already been done by Kadison in the paper I reference above.  The trouble here is mostly topological and in entails proving that pointwise-weak continuity implies bounded-weak continuity which is actually not that hard.